# Firefox - Extension Load Order?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, styles, visual-styles

I am seeing an issue with Firefox 48.0.2 where it seems that the order in which plugins are loaded is affecting my browsing experience.

Basically, I try to keep everything in "night mode" due to two large monitors, a dark room, and developing all day (and night).  To this end, I have both "Stylish" and "Dark Background and Light Text" extensions installed.

Stylish is used for sites that have good, dark userstyles ... and the other extension blacks out pages that don't automatically.

Randomly, these seem to be stepping on each other.  For example, I have a Stylish userstyle for Google.com, and I have the other plugin ignore this domain.

It works about 80% of the time when I start Firefox, but occasionally they will both apply, in what seems to be an indeterminate order.

Is there any determinism to the order of operations in Firefox for loading extensions?   I have looked around but can't find any documentation.  Can the order be configured?   Does anyone know if this is a multi-threaded ordeal where they can start/end whenever?

Comment: Interesting and well written question +1 :)